# undefined function xdebug_code_coverage_started()

Tags: php, command-line, wamp, xdebug

I am trying to get Xdebug code coverage analysis for PHP working on the command line, but I get an undefined function error for code coverage functions. I am *not* using PHPUnit, and I'm *not* using an IDE. My text editor is Komodo Edit.

I am using:

- Windows 8
- PHP 5.4.12
- Apache 2.2.4 (but command-line PHP)
- WAMP

I downloaded Xdebug 2.2.4 for PHP 5.4 VC9 TS (64 bit) and followed the instructions on the [Xdebug install page](http://xdebug.org/wizard.php) to configure my computer.

I changed the php.ini files in C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin and C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12 to have the following settings for xdebug:

```
zend_extension = c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.4-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll

[xdebug]
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.profiler_enable = off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp/xdebug"
xdebug.idekey=xdebug
xdebug.remote_log="c:/wamp/tmp/xdebug/xdebug_remote.log"
xdebug.coverage_enable = on
```

I added XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=xdebug" to my environment variables. I then restarted WAMP.

When I try to call xdebug_code_coverage_started() from my script, I get

> PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function xdebug_code_coverage_started()

The same happens for any code coverage functions I try. However, `var_dump(xdebug_get_headers())` works. My phpinfo shows xdebug.coverage_enable is on.

I have also tried:

- not setting xdebug.coverage_enable (it defaults to on)
- not setting XDEBUG_CONFIG
- setting xdebug.remote_enable to off
- not setting xdebug.idekey, xdebug.remote_log, and xdebug.remote_autostart

all with the same results.

**How do I get PHP to recognize Xdebug code coverage functions?**

Comment: Is this still relevant? If so, is the dll actually in the folder pointed to in php.ini?

Comment: @Peter Yes, that's where the dll is.

Comment: Hello maybe you have to add quote for `c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.4-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll` like `"c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.4-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"`

Comment: The quotation around the .dll could be an issue. In XAMPP 1.7.3 on Windows 7 putting quotes around the .dll will cause issues. This could be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Hers is an example XDebug for php 5.3 or higher:

```
[Xdebug] zend_extension="<path to php_xdebug.dll>" 
xdebug.remote_enable=1 
xdebug.remote_port="<the port for Xdebug to listen to>" 
(the default port is 9000) 
xdebug.profiler_enable=1 
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="<AMP home\tmp>"
```

try to get it to as close as possible and restart WAMP.